# Why must \DeclareMathOperator be in the preamble?

Tags: amsmath

What is the rationale for requiring `\DeclareMathOperator` to be in the preamble?

Why are users not allowed to restrict the scope of an operator definition to a particular chapter or environment, like `\newcommand`?

Comment: I would like to upvote this question 10 times... related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93774/why-does-latex-make-declaremathsymbol-and-declaresymbolfont-preamble-only

Comment: @jfbu : Just read your the discussion from your question. Since `\DeclareMathOperator` doesn't necessarily involve loading new symbol, I wonder if we can find a satisfactory explanation for mere math operators!

Comment: You can use `\newcommand` any any place, you can as well ```\catcode`\\=\active```, but I will call you names for doing so. Yours, Journal Typesetter.

Comment: Can't users use `\newcommand` freely **inside** the `document` environment?

Comment: @nicolai.rostov They can, but it's pretty unfortunate, since any processing of such document is pain-in-you-know-where. Cf. also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156754

Comment: although the discussion I linked too dates back somewhat, I still had it somewhat on my mind, and failed to immediately appreciate on seeing your post that the situation is indeed much more user-friendly with regards to `\DeclareMathOperator`, as I explain in my just posted answer.

Comment: I could see reasons for allowing it in the document only for multiauthor collections, for instance the proceedings of a conference. Otherwise, changing the meaning of a command depending on the chapter is, in my opinion, quite disputable.

Comment: egreg and @tohecz : It may be. However, this is something a user needs to see by h(im|er)self, and not just refrain from doing because it's "frowned upon". Otherwise, it is like obeying the law only so as not to be arrested. No virtue in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of  `\DeclareMathOperator`, contrarily to the `LaTeX` issues raised in this question: [Why does LaTeX make \DeclareMathSymbol and \DeclareSymbolFont preamble-only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93774/why-does-latex-make-declaremathsymbol-and-declaresymbolfont-preamble-only), the user is provided  with a simple possibility to circumvent the `only-preamble` restriction: it is to use the `\operatorname` or `\operatornamewithlimits` command, also provided by `amsmath` (or more precisely `amsopn` where `\DeclareMathOperator` is defined and made preamble only).

> [image: declare math operator in environment]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\textbackslash COS has meaning: \meaning\COS}

\texttt{\textbackslash cos has meaning: \meaning\cos}

\begin{large}
  \newcommand{\COS}{\operatorname{COS}}
  In this environment the math operator \verb|\COS| is defined: $\COS(x)=\cos(x)$.

\texttt{\textbackslash COS has meaning: \meaning\COS}
\end{large}

\texttt{\textbackslash COS now has meaning: \meaning\COS}

\end{document}
```

As an aside, there is an issue with `\DeclareMathOperator` and Unicode engines (if the minus sign is made a Unicode math character), which is fixed under `lualatex` by loading package [lualatex-math](http://ctan.org/pkg/lualatex-math)

Comment: `\operatornamewithlimits` is deprecated; `\operatorname*` does the same.

Comment: @egreg: I had looked at `amsopn.sty`, not `amsopn.dtx` which mentions indeed: _For backwards compatibility we keep this old command name for the time being_.

Answer (score 10):

I guess there are two components to an answer to your "why" question.

Most immediately, there's an `\@onlypreamble` qualifier for many setup-type macros of the `amsmath` package to make sure they won't work if invoked outside the preamble. The macro `\DeclareMathOperator` is defined in the file `amsopn.sty`, which is loaded by `amsmath.sty`; note the instruction `\@onlypreamble\DeclareMathOperator` at ca line 57 of `amsopn.sty`.

You might then ask, so why is the `\@onlypreamble` qualifier imposed? I wasn't involved in the design or creation of the `amsmath` package, but I'd say a reasonable guess is that the creators were adhering to the spirit of the LaTeX2e format, which strongly encourages separating matters of *content* from matters of *visual display* of the content. The latter matters are supposed to be taken care of in the preamble.

To address your related concern, i.e., having various chapters that may require different definitions of one and the same operator-type macro. For concreteness, let's say the operator is called `\det`. The creators of the `amsmath` package either didn't envisage a use case such as the one you've set forth here or, quite possibly, they may have believed that it's better to define all possible variants of `\det` -- say, `\detA` and `\detB` -- in the preamble and then execute a `\let` of `\det` to either `\detA` or `\detB` at the start of each chapter.

Comment: it wasn't so much purity as necessity: if you used amsmath on emtex on a 512KB PC in 1993 you had hardly any bytes left for any user commands or cross references, `\@onlypreamble` any commands that we could get rid of, freed up enough memory that you could (just about) typeset a hello world document without running out of memory.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Many thanks for clarifying what actually went on in the runup to the introduction of LaTeX2e and the `amsmath` package. :-)